# Bulk insertion into a table using a foreign surrogate key, when only the natural key is available

Tags: mysql

What are the ways to initially fill associations (or other tables) that refer to a base table using a surrogate key, when the data only has natural keys? What's best practice (e.g. one `INSERT...SELECT` per row, temporary tables, code solution outside SQL)?

For an example to work with, take the venerable Author-Book schema, with tables for authors (natural key: name), books (natural key: name & year) and a join table to connect the two in a many-to-many relationship. Imagine that the source data associates authors with books (so no surrogate key yet exists) and is to be imported into the MySQL database.

Source data:

```
'Terry Pratchett', 'The Colour of Magic', 1983
'Terry Pratchett', 'Good Omens', 1990
'Neil Gaiman', 'Good Omens', 1990
'Neil Gaiman', 'Neverwhere', 1996
'Terry Pratchett', 'Dodger', 2012
```

Sample definition:

```
CREATE TABLE authors (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE books (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `year` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (`name`, `year`)
);

CREATE TABLE authors_books (
    `author` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `book` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`author`) REFERENCES authors (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`book`) REFERENCES books (`id`)
);
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO authors (`name`)
  VALUES
('Neil Gaiman'),
('Terry Pratchett');

INSERT INTO books (`name`, `year`)
  VALUES
('The Colour of Magic', 1983),
('Good Omens', 1990),
('Neverwhere', 1996),
('Dodger', 2012);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a (temporary) table with the natural keys to hold the source data, and join on this table to fill the association table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE source_authors_books (
    `author` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `book` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `year` SMALLINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO source_authors_books VALUES ... -- source data

INSERT INTO authors_books
  SELECT authors.id, books.id
    FROM source_authors_books AS source
      JOIN authors ON source.author = authors.name
      JOIN books ON source.book = books.name
                AND source.year = books.year
```

Source data integrity could be checked in two ways:

1. by adding foreign key restraints to `source_authors_books` before inserting data, in which case integrity errors will prevent the import from happening (and give error messages).
2. by issuing a `SELECT` similar to the one in the `INSERT`, but using outer joins and checking for `NULL` IDs.